# Error: Linking an existing Git Bash Project with Git. Windows 10. GNU Bash, version 4.4.23(1) - release

Tags: r, version-control, git-bash

I've created an R Project that isn't under version control, and I need to link it with Github using Git Bash. The project is called *New_Project* and it's located at `c/Users/Owner/Desktop/New_Project`. The picture attached shows the ways I've attempted to navigate to the directory containing my project using Git Bash, but I keep receiving the following errors:

```
bash: cd: no such file or directory

bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you[Git Bash Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMfpp.png)

Comment: How about `cd ~/Desktop/New_Project`

Comment: Also, tab completion should work, So if you type `cd ~/` then `<tab>` it should list all the possible next steps in the path.

Comment: @MrFlick using 'cd ~/'  '<tab>' helped me find the file on my laptop and helped me realize that the file is actually called *New_Project.Rproj*. I used 'cd/Desktop/New_Project.Rproj' but still got the error "No such file or directory"

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The `Rproj`  file is usually just a file, not a folder. You can't `cd` "into" a file. Are you sure `New_Project.Rproj` is a folder? Did you just give it an usual name? Also did you have a space and tilde in your actual `cd` command (it seems to be missing in your comment)

Comment: Success! Confirmed `Rproj` is a file, not a folder. Instead of trying to `cd` the file, I `cd`ed the folder, and I was able to link the `Rproj` files in the folder to my Github. Thank you!

Comment: I believe my mistake was that I was trying to `cd` the file, instead of the folder

Comment: @SwezenKizito Yes, I have detail the difference between the file and its parent folder in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ is replaced by `/c/Users/Owner` (which is `$HOME`) so that would explain the `/c/Users/Owner/c/Users/Owner` path.

And if your actual Windows login is *not* `Owner`, I suspect you are meant to replace `Owner` by your Windows login account.

```
cd /c/Users/<myWindowsLogin>/Desktop/New_Project
```

Whatever the parent folder is, you should find in it, as [documented by RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects):

> - a project file (with an `.Rproj` extension) within the project directory.
>   This file contains various project options and can also be used as a shortcut for opening the project directly from the filesystem.
> - a hidden directory (named `.Rproj.user`) where project-specific temporary files (e.g. auto-saved source documents, window-state, etc.) are stored.
>   This directory is also automatically added to `.Rbuildignore`, `.gitignore`, etc. if required.